# NVActivityIndicatorView only for particular view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using this library https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView for showing the loading indicator. By default it blocks the entire view controller but how can I show the activity indicator only for the particular view. For example if a view controller contains a webview and some other view, the activity indicator should be only for the webview and I should be able interact with the other view.

```
class FaqViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet var faqWebView: UIWebView!
    static let activityData = ActivityData()
    var activityIndicator : NVActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        faqWebView.delegate = self
        faqWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        NVActivityIndicatorView.DEFAULT_BLOCKER_SIZE = CGSize(width: 45, height: 45)
        NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.startAnimating(FaqViewController.activityData)
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: whats your `UIWebView` frame

Comment: As of now it fills the entire view. But I want to interact with the Navigation controller at any point of time to go back even when page is loading.

Comment: change the frame of your `NVActivityIndicatorView` using `let x = self.view.center.x
    let y = self.view.center.y

    let frame = CGRect(x: (x - 50), y: (y - 50), width: 100, height: 100)
    NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: frame)`

Comment: I tried this but now loading indicator itself is not shown.

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for e.g show the `activityIndicator`

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
{
    //NVActivityIndicatorView.DEFAULT_BLOCKER_SIZE = CGSize(width: 45, height: 45)
    //NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.startAnimating(FaqViewController.activityData)

    let xAxis = self.view.center.x // or use (view.frame.size.width / 2) // or use (faqWebView.frame.size.width / 2)
    let yAxis = self.view.center.y // or use (view.frame.size.height / 2) // or use (faqWebView.frame.size.height / 2)



let frame = CGRect(x: (xAxis - 50), y: (yAxis - 50), width: 45, height: 45)
 activityIndicator = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: frame)
activityIndicator.type = . ballScale // add your type
activityIndicator.color = UIColor.red // add your color

self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator) // or use  webView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

for hide

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error)
    {
        hideactivityIndicator()
    }

   func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!)
    {
      hideactivityIndicator()
    }

  func hideactivityIndicator()
  {

  activityIndicator. stopAnimating()
  activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
  }
```

Comment: i tried the same for imageview but it didn't work? May I know what would be the problem. The imageview is a subview of a view.

Comment: imageview means

Comment: imageview means UIImageView which holds the UIImage

Comment: ha ha ha bro, imageview contains UIimage proerty , what u tried whats your concept

Comment: I have to load the image from the server. Untill it loads I have to show the loading indicator in that particular view alone.

Comment: your coding is sync or async , if sync is not show the loading indicator

Comment: I am using Alamofire to make a network call which is async network call.

Comment: then use Alamofire imageloader concept for loading indicator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154647/discussion-between-prabu-raj-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it as a subView for the what ever the view you want to show it on. In you case you want to show only on UIWebView, then your code should look like

`self.faqWebView.addSubView(activityIndicator)`