# how to go back while NVActivityIndicatorView is start?

Tags: swift

I am using `NVActivityIndicatorView` as a spinner in my project. When I decided to go back, I am waiting until the spinner stops. So I have to go back while spinner is loading.

```
import UIKit
import NVActivityIndicatorView
import Foundation

class Utilities: UIViewController,NVActivityIndicatorViewable
{
    func startprogress()
    {
        let size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        startAnimating(size, message: nil, type:
            NVActivityIndicatorType(rawValue: 12)!)
    }

    func stopprogress() {
        self.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

In my view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Utilities().startprogress()
    apiMethod()
}
```

after my response success I am stopping activity indicator

```
func apiMethod()
{


    let onSuccess: ((_: NSDictionary) -> Void)? = {(_ response: NSDictionary) -> Void in

        print(response)
        Utilities().stopprogress()

    }
```

Here I am facing issue is I have to wait until the indicator stops to go back.

[image]

Comment: where you add NVActivityIndicatorView?

Comment: i am not adding NVActivityIndicatorView in main storyboard just calling startprogress() in viewDidLoad

Comment: Add `NVActivityIndicatorView` on `ViewController` instead of `Window`.

Comment: added still coming above the navigation bar

Comment: Can you attach your code snippet where you add the utilities class in viewController?

Comment: updated my question please check

Comment: Understand my question. Add your code where you added `utilities  ViewController` as as subclass or as a subView ?

Comment: More precisely what this method does - `startAnimating` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the `activityIndicator` on the main UIWindow. you have to add that `activityIndicator` on only the particular `UIViewController`. 
If you need any help regarding that, refer following links.

https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView/issues/191
https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView/issues/174
[NVActivityIndicatorView only for particular view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234193/nvactivityindicatorview-only-for-particular-view)

Comment: Is there any process to bring navigation bar infront of indicator